# Advice for website authentication system that queries facebook API

Tags: php, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've built a website that authenticates users via facebook.

The way I've set it up is like this: The website uses the facebook JS SDK on the front end, and when the user authenticates with facebook their access_token is sent to my server via an ajax call (using HTTPS for security) - where the graph api is queried and their session is initiated server-side (Using a database for secure session storage of user data).

Can anyone think of any potential problems this approach might lead to? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common scenario.  The only issue is that unless you request offline_access that token you get is only valid for an hour.